# Sent XMR To My Desktop GUI Wallet From BEFORE being fully synced - Daemon is Synced but XMR is Still Not in Wallet? Any Help Would Be Great

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monerod, daemon, synchronization, transaction-data

I made a stupid mistake... Sent XMR To My Desktop GUI Wallet From Kucoin BEFORE being fully synced. Kucoin says "sent successful" to my Wallet ID - I didn't realize I had not yet synced. It finally synced and still nothing showing in my wallet. I followed instructions from another post and changed my block height to the current date, and let it fully sync, and still nothing. I also tried setting to a date prior to my transaction and let that fully sync... still nothing. I'm using Simple mode (bootstrap), but have also tried advanced, remote node and nothing seems to be working. Any help would be VERY appreciated.

I also looked up the BlockChain Record link and have all the details for that I could provide, like the number of conformations and block height, transaction hash, etc. I know it's still on the blockchain but kind of freaking out.

Also, does it matter what the wallet set up is, i.e., Simple mode, bootstrap, or advance if I'm trying to recover a wallet? Can I use a simple mode just to get some kind of confirmation that my transaction was received?

Comment: In the CLI run the command `rescan_bc` (or whatever is the equivalent in the GUI).

Comment: Okay, any idea, or does anyone know what the GUI command is for this process?

In the GUI there is a Rescan Wallet option, under settings-wallet, think that's the same?

Comment: There's a button labeled "Rescan wallet balance"; one would assume that's the equivalent.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that with no luck in seeing any change in the account balance; that's why I asked for clarification on the GUI name.

Comment: It's probably because you have a restore height later than when you sent the funds to your new wallet. Just create another wallet with the same seed and set a restore height *before* the height your tx was made.

Comment: we suspect a race condition in the GUI where usually one transaction can be missing. It's a rare event so kinda hard to pinpoint the cause.

Comment: @jtgrassie "Rescan wallet balance" calls "rescan_spent", not "rescan_bc"

Comment: Please see the guide I linked.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> Info -> Wallet restore height

Click `Change` and press Ok twice, this will trigger a rescan.